# Add new field to mongo if not exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I have this document in my mongo-db

```
{
    "key": 1,
    "name" "abc"
  }
```

now I want to update it and want to set age as 20 so  I used update query by keeping upsert as true but its not updating as age field don't exist , how can I make query so it create the field if it doses not exist

Comment: With `$set` operator, it will add the `age` field if it does not exist, otherwise, it will override the existing value for the field. The `upsert: true` setting is used for creating a new document if there is no matched document, otherwise it will update the existing matched document.

Comment: as already mentioned i used it

Comment: Please show your query. And since you use Mongoose, also provide the response returned. To check the matched Count and updated count.  Provide minimal, reproducible example but not just complain it is not working without any info.

Comment: Would you please put your entire query.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the findOneAndUpdate function

Refer to https://sparkbyexamples.com/mongodb/mongodb-insert-if-not-exists/?amp=1

```
db.findOneAndUpdate(
   { key:1 },
   { $setOnInsert: { key: 1,name:”abc”,age: 20 } }, 
   { upsert: true, returnOriginal: false }
)
```

Comment: its not working as I mentioned

Comment: What’s the exact error ?

Comment: no error just thing getting executed and nothing happening

Comment: You should see some sort of output as in acknowledgement : true

Answer (score 1):

you can make changes in schema to add new fields
use option: strict as false refer this
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html
and then you can use query to updete that field

```
db.findOneAndUpdate(
   { key:1 },
   { $setOnInsert: { key: 1,name:”abc”,age: 20 } }, 
   { upsert: true, returnOriginal: false }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

> If the field does not exist,
> `$set`
> will add a new field with the specified value

[doccumentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)

```js
db.collection.updateOne(
  { "key": 1 }, 
  { $set: { "name": "abc", "age": 20 } }, // The update operation using $set to update "name" and set "age" to 20
  { upsert: true } // Optional: Set to true to insert a new document if no matching document is found
);
```

Comment: its not working as I mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Usual `db.findOneAndUpdate` should work, but I had the same results.

```
await Dummy.findOneAndUpdate({
    key: 1,
  }, {
    name: 'cba',
  },
);
```

The problem was with the schema. I had to add the new `name` field as optional

```
const Dummy = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    // required: false which is default
  },
  ...
});
```